# Why are the leaves on my Aloe Vera flattening?

Tags: houseplants, leaves, aloe

[image]

I recently potted my aloe Vera plant near a south west facing window. I watered once last week and I noticed that the aloe Vera leaves started to flatten. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Once a week is too much water. I water my aloe once a month inside.  I rarely water outside. I have had my aloe about 15 years it is in a 18 Gallon terracotta pot. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Your plant is fine.  Go ahead and snip the tip on the leaf at 11:00 and cut out the leaf at 9:00 (on a clock face)?  The little on at 2:00?  Cut it off beneath the soil.

Water sparingly and sporadically. You do have to give it a little balanced fertilizer once in a great while.